# How to get results based upon latitude and longitude and multiple distance ranges in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, geocode

I have a events model and its geo coded properly and I am using [Geocode gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder).

I have latitude and longitude for a current location(Assume latitude=  12.9716 and longitude=77.209) and I want to get all the events within a range of 10km to 25km. So query is like:

```
 Event.near([12.9716, 77.209], 25, unit: :km, min_radius: 10)
```

But I want get results from range 10-25kms or 100-150kms. 
A stupid way of doing is:

```
  events_1 = Event.near([12.9716, 77.209], 25, unit: :km, min_radius: 10)
  events_2 = Event.near([12.9716, 77.209], 150, unit: :km, min_radius: 100)
  events = events_1 + events_2
```

How to get that data in single query?